# Анимация у ProgressBar не работает

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar

Не понимаю причины почему не работает **ProgressBar**.
При запуске этого кода просто синее кольцо без движения

**Android Studio 2.2,**
 **SDK API 25**

**Activity.class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar mprogressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.circular_android_progress_bar);

        mprogressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circular_progress_bar);
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mprogressBar, "progress", 0, 100);
        anim.setDuration(15000);
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.start();
    }
}
```

**circular_android_progress_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/circular_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="48"
        android:progress="1"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progressbar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:text="ViralAndroid.com"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**circular_progressbar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому Ваш circular_progressbar.xml -- это и есть просто синее кольцо. Даже если бы оно у Вас вращалось (а Вы его нигде не вращаете), то Вы бы этого не заметили.

Советую посмотреть вот [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog), а точнее [конкретно вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7304685/3100967) на него, где приводится пример именно кругового прогресс бара. Обратите внимание на XML-теги `rotate` и `gradient`. При этом, для бесконечного прогресса достаточно просто установить Ваш дровабл в XML-разметке, `ObjectAnimator`'ом ничего делать не нужно.

Если же Вам важно отображать именно процент выполнения, возможно, проще воспользоваться готовыми решениями, например [этим](https://github.com/eralpyucel/CircleProgressView).

P.S. `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` явно лишнее для circular прогресс бара.

Answer (score 0):

У вас стоит тэг `indeterminate = false`, попробуйте устангвить `true`